# php web site displays file instead of downloading

Tags: php, linux, azure-web-app-service

I am running a php 8 website on linux web app service in Azure. When the user presses a button I want to create a file on the fly (read data from db) and download it. Instead it is displaying contents on the page.
Here is the code

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=geodata.csv");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("geodata.csv"));

$file = fopen('php://output', 'w') 
            or die ("Unable to create file in write mode");
if (ob_get_contents()) ob_end_clean();
    fputcsv($output, array('name','loc','zip'), chr(6));
    $mrows = mysqli_query($myconnection, "SELECT name,loc,zip FROM geo_tbl WHERE sp = 'FL'");
    while ($mrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mrows)) {
        fputcsv($file, $mrow, chr(6));
    }
    fclose($file);
    readfile("geodata.csv");
    exit();
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you configure PHP into your Web Server

Comment: Dont see anywhere where yo make a connection to the database either, so the `mysqli_query()` may not work if `$myconnection` has never been set

Comment: I am using Azure app service (linux). Haven't done any config. Was playing with .htaccess but deleted it. The code to set db connection is omitted for brevity sake. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a web server installed?

Comment: I dont have a web server installed. I am using Azure app service to host the application (with a linux app service plan) The stack is php 8.0/linux.

Comment: So you are running it like `php -S localhost:8080`

Comment: Just to add, I can see the web server being used on Azure is nginx/1.14.2 and the php version is 8.0.3.

Comment: Not doing anything locally. Installed the app on Azure cloud using linux/php8

Comment: _Instead it is displaying contents on the page_ Does this mean its showing the PHP code OR the file you are sending

Comment: Ok so You do have a web server, its nginx

Comment: You have two `Content-Type` headers.  To force a download, you only need `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');` per Example #1 on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: It is showing the contents of the file. So it fetched the data alright but then just pastes the data on the page instead of displaying the download menu.

Comment: @Alan. That was good observation. Alas, it didnt resolve the issue. Still seeing the content.

Comment: I have made the code simpler - just trying to download an existing file. Now, nothing happens when I click the download button. Extected the download dialog.                                         $filename = "test.txt";
$file = "/files/".$filename;
header('Content-type: text/plain');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
while (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
 }
 readfile($file);

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues with the code:

1. As Alan as already pointed out, you have duplicate `Content-Type` headers. If you are saving the file as an attachment, you can really use either one.
2. You issue your `die` message after you have already set the `Content-Type` header for a `csv` file so the message would not be displayed correctly. You should therefore do the `fopen` statement before setting the content header.
3. You are sending part of your output to variable `$output` instead of `$file` with the statement `fputcsv($output, array('name','loc','zip'), chr(6));` and that variable does not seem to be defined.
4. You are setting a `Content-Length` header with `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("geodata.csv"));` but at this point you have no idea what the content length is.
5. You should put double-quotes around your filename in the `Content-Disposition` header.

Although not errors, *per se*, you are retrieving the rows with `fetch_assoc` so `$mrow` will contain keys and values. You really only need to be using `fetch_row`. I also question your use of `chr(6)`, which is an ACK character, as a column delimiter. Did you possibly mean `chr(9)`, a TAB?

I believe the following is all you need:

```
<?php

//define (DELIMITER, chr(9)); // Shouldn't it be this?
define (DELIMITER, chr(6));

if (ob_get_contents()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}
$file = fopen('php://output', 'w') or die ("Unable to create file in write mode");

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="geodata.csv"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');

fputcsv($file, array('name','loc','zip'), DELIMITER);
$mrows = mysqli_query($myconnection, "SELECT name,loc,zip FROM geo_tbl WHERE sp = 'FL'");
while ($mrow = mysqli_fetch_row($mrows)) {
    fputcsv($file, $mrow, DELIMITER);
}
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

> When the user presses a button

Simply add the download attribute to your button, it should work straight away.

```
<a href="link/to/your/file.csv" download="filename.csv">Download link</a>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, there are several issues with your code.

But if you just remove the second content-type header and keep it as `application/octet-stream`, this should force a download.

However, your content-length will not be reported correctly. Perhaps read the contents into a variable, then take the length of that string as the `content-length` header.